# CSS/HTML Animation Circle to Square. Which property/attribute determines the Shape?

Tags: css, html, sass

> In the included example found on [codepen from CSS-Tricks](http://codepen.io/team/css-tricks/pen/EjaJNd) , which
>   property in the css code determines the shape of the div?
>
> I understand most of the css properties here. I am just wondering what
>   determines the shape, and if there is a way to describe/or make other
>   shapes. For example a star or triangle.
>
> I am new to css and would like to learn the language, especially
>   animation tricks.

```css
.element {
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: red;
  animation-name: stretch;
  animation-duration: 1.5s; 
  animation-timing-function: ease-out; 
  animation-delay: 0;
  animation-direction: alternate;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-fill-mode: none;
  animation-play-state: running;
}

@keyframes stretch {
  0% {
    transform: scale(.3);
    background-color: red;
    border-radius: 100%;
  }
  50% {
    background-color: orange;
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1.5);
    background-color: yellow;
  }
}

body,
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="element"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shape here is determined by `border-radius`, which can be used to round out the edges of an HTML element (turning a box into a rounded rectangle), or with enough radius (or `border-radius: 50%`), it can transform a square element into a circle. There's no similar way to produce other shapes (triangle, star, etc), though there are many outside-the-box and creative ways to do this, like using [borders to make a CSS triangle](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/).

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you!

Comment: @akasoggybunz Here is the demo, take a look: https://codepen.io/hirenalken/pen/jzEprN